# Serving favicon next.js

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I am using the boilerplate [Next.js starter](https://github.com/iaincollins/nextjs-starter). In `index.js`, an instance of the express application is defined as `expressApp`. I am simply attempting to serve my favicon using `serve-favicon` and having no luck:

```
expressApp.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, "static", "brand", "favicon.ico")));
```

Checked the path that is being resolved and it is correct. How does next.js implementation of `express` differ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [`serve-favicon`](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-favicon) repository:

> **Note** This module is exclusively for serving the "default, implicit favicon",
>   which is `GET /favicon.ico`. For additional vendor-specific icons that require
>   HTML markup, additional middleware is required to serve the relevant files, for
>   example [serve-static](https://npmjs.org/package/serve-static).

So it's not possible with this package to serve a favicon in another path, because that would require adding markup. To fix this, add a `link` tag inside your `pages/_document.js` template:

```babel
<Head>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/brand/favicon.ico" />
</Head>
```

While keeping your `serve-favicon` code in the `index.js` file:

```babel
expressApp.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, "static", "brand", "favicon.ico")));
```

Comment: Adding the link tag has worked *(although the path was slightly incorrect)*. I did not need to still serve it via express. Why did you think I did?

Comment: You don't need to because Next.js is hosting the `static` folder publicly at `/` by default. However, `serve-favicon` comes with a few optimizations such as setting certain headers for the favicon file. If you don't need those set, `serve-favicon` is not necessary.

Comment: Understood. Thank you! Also, about the path being incorrect, `/brand/favicon.ico` responded with a 404 but when I prepended `static` into the path it was fine

Comment: When you still use `serve-favicon`, or did you remove that?

Comment: Either. It required the '/static' either way